# How to send errors to .log file in python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, error-handling

Even I searched in the google, did not find.
I am struggling with the code. Please help me.
My requirement is simple:
If any error occured, need to send to .log file for the below program.But below code is not capturing in .log file.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import time
import logging
df= pd.read_csv('Testing.csv')

logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs even debug messages

fh = logging.FileHandler("Archieve\\spam.log")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.addHandler(fh)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you all the imports are properly resolved with installing respective dependencies.

Then make sure you have a file named "Testing.csv" in your current working directory or PYTHONPATH.

Finally make sure, you have folder named "Archieve" in your current working directory, if it is not there, create it first.

> mkdir Archieve

Finally see the log file in Archieve folder.

> cat Archieve\spam.log

Comment: I have Testing.csv and Archieve folder in the Python directory.But spam.log is not capturing if Testing.csv is not existed or loading is failed. I want to send every error into that log. Please help me.

Comment: Any answer, please?